# How to dynamically create spring addViewController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

How to dynamically create spring addViewController?

I have the following sources:

```
registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("admin/test/test");
registry.addViewController("/test2").setViewName("admin/test2/test2");
registry.addViewController("/test3").setViewName("admin/test3/test3");
...
```

I want to do url mapping according to the html name in the template folder like this, but I'm curious how it is possible.

Best Regards!

Comment: List files, add mapping? Basically learn to use the Java API for files?

Comment: @M. Deinum I mean List files, add mapping!

Comment: As stated learn the file API (although in this case the classpath for scanning).